# Как при помощи стримов/лямб вывести элементы массива/списка JAVA

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Есть массив:

```
Integer[] sums = new Integer[5];
```

предварительно уже заполненный элементами.

Для вывода элементов c новой строки при помощи функционала [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) используется:

```
Arrays.stream(sums).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Как сделать вывод,например, в одну строку, через запятую(после последнего элемента ничего) при помощи java8?

В одну строку `print ()`, добавить запятую внутри `forEach ()`, судя по всему, нельзя. Так еще нужно проверить условие на последний элемент.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, стримы созданы для преобразования каждого отдельного элемента, независимо от предыдущих. 
Поэтому с проверкой последнего ничего не выйдет, если не костылизировать через limit и skip с созданием второй копии стрима.

Если нужен именно стрим, то я предложу только такой вариант:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(sums)
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

Comment: а есть способ провернуть такой же финт ушами с массивом типа int[]? Загвоздка в том, чтобы одним методом привести int к String

Comment: mapToObject() решает вопрос. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, так:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(sums).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.stream()
                .map((s) -> s + " ")
                .forEach((s) -> out.print(s));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Конечно, костыльный метод, но могу предложить:

```
String tmp =""+sums[0];
for(int i=1; i<5; i++){
    tmp+=", "+sums[i];
}
System.out.print(tmp);
```

Comment: вопрос был именно в использовании стримов, а не в использование обычного for